# Is it healthy for a pitpull puppy to spend months in one place without leaving?

Tags: dogs, health, psychology, socializing, animal-handling

I have a puppy of almost 4 months who lives in the roof of the building where I live.

The problem is that because of my work it is impossible for me to take her for a walk, the most I could do is take her out for a walk every 2 months. 
 And so it will be for at least another 2 continuous years.

Would it be good for the puppy to have a life like that?

Are there bad consequences about this?

Or should I look for a home in which she can walk frequently?

The puppy is very affectionate with me by the way and I really don't like the idea of looking for a new home with other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppies *really* need a lot of engagement and socialisation - its not a toy, and walks are *important*, they get your dog used to the environment around them and to get to know other dogs and humans, which is important, especially for breeds that get kinda attached to their owners, like pitties.

A dog is an investment in time and energy *especially* in the early days. A tired, well played with puppy is a *good* puppy, they're less likely to chew up your home (this is important!) and be socially well adjusted. Leaving your dog alone is a sure way to end up with a poor dear who has no idea what to do (just like with people! You wouldn't leave a baby all alone for 2 years right?).

You don't *have* to give up your dog though. I know people walk their dogs at night after work. I used to wake up early (back when my dog was younger and didn't mind walking up early) to walk him - before dawn.

Having a dog means adjustment. Walking your dog every 2 months essentially means your dog's deprived of a good chunk of its childhood. 
Its also worth considering, if you don't have time to walk your dog, you'd want to see how much quality play time you have with the dog. It might be worth asking around if there's folks in your family willing to help or working out a schedule that works. *AT LEAST* daily walks - 2's probably better. Being able to socialise with people and other dogs is also essential. Your dog isn't going to get this with bimonthly walks.

Comment: And if I get my puppy a new friend?
I have a neighbor who lives with his dog, I could tell him to 'lend' his dog. The problem would not be solved if the 2 dogs coexisted daily?

Comment: eh, less so. Then you have... two unsupervised dogs. Could your neighbour be convinced to dogsit in the short run? I don't think this is really sustainable in the long run - our dog was bought by someone who probably loved him a lot but just couldn't afford the commitment, but would give you breathing room to work out how to balance a dog and work

Comment: what do you mean by dogsit?

Comment: Babysit, but with dogs - basically give the pup some "adult supervision" so he gets to bond with someone 'not in the family' and keep him out of trouble. To me, the secret of a happy well adjusted dog is to get them as many experiences as possible when they're still young and mallible. Get them used to as many people, dogs, and places, especially in the first 6 months. They grow up so fast, and this is what makes your dog who he will be as.

Comment: oh good to know, I'll try to modify my schedule, it will be difficult but I'll try.

Comment: Do try - You won't regret it.